# Python Inheritance and Class (Hackerank problem)

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge

I just deep dived to Python and I came with this [Hackerrank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-inheritance/problem):

Create two class, `Person` with `firstName`, `lastName`, `idNumber` as its attributes with method `printPerson()` simply print last name and first name and id, and the derived class `Student`.

The `Student` class has additional attributes, its score and an array with two value, and I need to calculate the average of all scores in this array. Then finally I will decide which letter I should assign to this average score and print it.

Sample Input:

```
Heraldo Memelli 8135627
2
100 80
```

Sample Output:

```
Name: Memelli, Heraldo
ID: 8135627
Grade: O
```

My code in Python 3:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, idNumber):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.idNumber = idNumber
    def printPerson(self):
        print("Name:", self.lastName + ",", self.firstName)
        print("ID:", self.idNumber)

def avg(a):
    return sum(a)/len(a)

def m(a):
    return [int(r) for r in list(a.values())[0].split('-')]

class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, f, l, i, s):
        Person.__init__(self, f, l, i)
        self.s = s
    def calculate(self):
        avgScore = avg(self.s) 
        scoreList = [
          {'O': '90-100'},
          {'E': '80-89'},
          {'A': '70-79'},
          {'P': '55-69'},
          {'D': '40-54'},
          {'T': '0-39'},
        ]
        scoreLetter = list([x for x in scoreList if m(x)[0] <= avgScore == avgScore <=m(x)[1]][0].keys())[0]
        return '{}'.format(scoreLetter)

line = input().split()
firstName = line[0]
lastName = line[1]
idNum = line[2]
numScores = int(input()) # not needed for Python
scores = list( map(int, input().split()) )
s = Student(firstName, lastName, idNum, scores)
s.printPerson()
print("Grade:", s.calculate())
```

It passes all test cases. Could you please help me to review it and give me some advice?

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Read [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) the Python style guide

  Functions and variables should be `lower_snake_case`
- Naming

  Single letter variable names are a bad habit. Code should be self explanatory and function names like `m()` don't tell what they are supposed to do
- Instead of the `printPerson()` function, override the magic function `__str__`

  Doing this you can do `print(student)` to print the class
- You should make the `avg` function a part of the `Student` class
- Your grade function can be simplified

  > ```
  >  scoreList = [
  >    {'O': '90-100'},
  >    {'E': '80-89'},
  >    {'A': '70-79'},
  >    {'P': '55-69'},
  >    {'D': '40-54'},
  >    {'T': '0-39'},
  > ]
  > ```

  When you swap the key and values around, and loop over them in order

  ```
  self.score_dictionary = {
      90 : 'O',
      80 : 'E',
      70 : 'A',
      55 : 'P',
      40 : 'D',
      0  : 'T'
  }
  ```

  It becomes clear that if the average is higher than the value that should be the grade to give, else go to the next value

  This will happen automatically with Python3.7+, or else you can make use of an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

  ```
  from collections import OrderedDict
  self.score_dictionary = OrderedDict([
      (90, 'O'),
      (80, 'E'),
      (70, 'A'),
      (55, 'P'),
      (40, 'D'),
      (0, 'T')
  ])
  ```

  Thnx [@Graipher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/98493/graipher), for correcting my mistake regarding the OrderedDict

  Another way (which might be clearer) is to loop over the dictionary keys in sorted order
- You can unpack multiple arguments in one go

  > ```
  > line = input().split()
  > firstName = line[0]
  > lastName = line[1]
  > idNum = line[2]
  > ```

  Could be

  ```
  f, l, i = input().split()
  ```
- It is Python idion to use `_` for variables you don't use

## Code

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, id):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.id = id

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Name: {self.last_name}, {self.first_name}\nID: {self.id}"

class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self,  first_name, last_name, id, scores):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, id)
        self.scores = scores
        self.avg = sum(self.scores) / len(scores)
        self.score_dictionary = {
            90 : 'O',
            80 : 'E',
            70 : 'A',
            55 : 'P',
            40 : 'D',
            0  : 'T'
        }

    def grade(self):
        for score in sorted(self.score_dictionary.keys(), reverse=True):
            if self.avg >= score:
                return self.score_dictionary[score]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f, l, i = input().split()
    _ = input()
    scores = list(map(int, input().split()))
    student = Student(f, l, i, scores)
    print(student)
    print(f"Grade: {student.grade()}")
```

Comment: And the naming scheme and having to define a `printPerson` method was required in the problem, but recommending the normal best-practice is still good.

Comment: Thank you @Graipher and Ludisposed, I upvoted all of you, I will try to understand, thank you again for helping me!